# Mean and variance of beta looking distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

From lecture notes on SDE's. I have calculated a stationary distribution of an SDE from the forward kolmogorov equation. I can not, however, identify this distribution and I want to find the mean and variance. The pdf is.

$f(x)=\frac{(x^2+1)^{-\left(\frac{\sigma^2+\lambda}{\sigma^2} \right)}\Gamma\left( \frac{\sigma^2+\lambda}{\sigma^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sigma^2+\lambda}{\sigma^2} \right)}$

Where $\lambda,\sigma$ are real scalars and $\Gamma$ is the gamma function. It looks like a beta-distribution, but I cannot wrangle it into a form where it yields it's mean and variance?

Comment: It's a Student $t$, actually. That'll give what you need.

Comment: That is exactly what it is, thank you so much!

Comment: I think strictly it may be a scaled Student $t$.  In any case if $\lambda=0$ it is a Cauchy distribution with no mean, and if $0 \lt \lambda \le \sigma^2$ then it has no variance